# Spring throw CustomObject to JSON in controller

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot

I'm wanting to return/throw an object depending on some logic inside the controller.

For example lets say something required a user to login I'd want to return an appropriate message

```
throw a new ReturnLoginMessage("Must login", "xx@xx.com", 111)
```

I can't just throw ReturnLoginMessage as it'd just return the following:

```
"exception": "com.userapi.returntypes.ReturnLoginMessage"
```

Which is not useful at all! I'd want the ***JSON*** representation of that ***returnloginmessage*** object.

```
{
"message": "Must login", 
"email": "xx@xx.com", 
"code": "111"
}
```

Is this possible given the following controller? What this controller does is check to see if the user already exists, if it does, they must ***login*** (which is why I'm returning the returnloginmessage object.

```
@RequestMapping(value="login/email", method=RequestMethod.POST,  produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
UserCredential login(@RequestBody UserFacebookLoginContext body) throws IOException, InvalidKeySpecException,
            NoSuchAlgorithmException, ConfirmLogin, ClassNotFoundException, ConfirmResponse, InvalidRequestException, ConfirmLoginEmail {

... Logic that checks to see if user exists....
if (user does exist) 
    throw  new ReturnLoginMessage("Must login", "xx@xx.com", 111); // THis returns "exception": "com.userapi.returntypes.ReturnLoginMessage"
else if(other condition)
    throw new OtherMessage("...", "...");
else 
    return UserCredential;
```

Is there  away I can return a JSON representation of the ***ReturnLoginMessage***? Given the following Java object?

```
public class ReturnLoginMessage extends Exception {
    private int code;
    private String message;
    private String email;
    private Date timestamp;

    public ReturnLoginMessage(int code, String message) {
        this.code = code;
        this.email = email;
        this.timestamp = new Date();
    }

    public ReturnLoginMessage(String message, int code, String email) {
        super(message);
        this.code = code;
        this.email = email;
        this.timestamp = new Date();
    }

    ... Getters .... Setters ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this by declaring a new `ExceptionHandler` method for `ReturnLoginMessage.class`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38185925/error-handling-on-controller-springmvc/38187716#38187716) answer.

Other approach would be to extend the return value of the `login` to something more generic. For example:

1. Declare it return `Object` instead of `UserCredentials` and simply return ReturnLoginMessage instead of throwing it.
2. Declare it return `Map<String,Object>` and construct the proper key/value pairs for both scenarios. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34166458/returning-multiple-different-objects-in-restcontroller-method) answer

Answer (score 0):

I acheived almost same thing(perhaps) by this way

first

add a ExceptionHandler at your REST Controller and return your exception
as a JSON (put a @ResponseBody).

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/rest")
public class RestfulTodoController {

    @ExceptionHandler(ReturnLoginMessage.class)
    @ResponseBody
    public ReturnLoginMessage handleException(final ReturnLoginMessage e) {
        return e;
    }
    // and your login handler method

}
```

check whether response is Json and also returning type is ReturnLoginMessage at advice that extends AbstractMappingJacksonResponseBodyAdvice,
if response is ReturnLoginMessage then modify response as you like

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class MyResponseBodyAdvice extends AbstractMappingJacksonResponseBodyAdvice {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(final MethodParameter returnType,
            final Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> converterType) {
        return super.supports(returnType, converterType)
                && null != returnType.getMethodAnnotation(ResponseBody.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void beforeBodyWriteInternal(final MappingJacksonValue bodyContainer, final MediaType contentType,
            final MethodParameter returnType, final ServerHttpRequest request, final ServerHttpResponse response) {
            if (bodyContainer.getValue() instanceof ReturnLoginMessage) {
                //set some object as you like 
                bodyContainer.setValue();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

finally

register above your advice  as a Bean

```
@Configuration
public class WebAppConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public MyResponseBodyAdvice myResponseBodyAdvice() {
        return new MyResponseBodyAdvice();
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use Fasterxml Jackson library best JSON parser for Java 
 Fasterxml Jackson convert Java Collection directly into JSON.

Maven Dependency

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>${faster-xml-version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${faster-xml-version}</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>${faster-xml-version}</version>
  </dependency>
```

Controller Code

```
@RequestMapping(value="login/email", method=RequestMethod.POST,               produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
@ResponseBody
 Map<String, Object> login(@RequestBody UserFacebookLoginContext body)   throws IOException, InvalidKeySpecException,
        NoSuchAlgorithmException, ConfirmLogin,    
 ClassNotFoundException, ConfirmResponse, InvalidRequestException, 
 ConfirmLoginEmail {
  ... Logic that checks to see if user exists....
if (user does exist) 
   return Utility.getSuccessResponse("message","Must    
login","email","xx@xx.com","code",111);

 else if(other condition)
 return Utility.getSuccessResponse("", "");
  else 
 return Utility.getSuccessResponse("userCredential", UserCredential);
```

Utility Class

```
 public class Utility {

public static Map<String, Object> getSuccessResponse(Object... responseContent) {

    if (responseContent.length % 2 != 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    Map<String, Object> responseObject = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    Map<String, Object> responseList = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    for (int i = 0; i < responseContent.length; i = i + 2) {
        responseList.put(responseContent[i].toString(), responseContent[i + 1]);
    }
    responseObject.put("result", responseList);
    return responseObject;
}
```

}

Comment: if there is some issue with above code, let me know i will explain

Comment: Spring already allows you to do most of this out of the box. There's no reason to make it this complex.

Comment: @g00glen00b  that's right i need to use Spring if it's already provide but solution works fine for time being.